# How would I search for objects that begin with X

Tags: sosl

I'd like to be able to search for all leads, accounts, opportunities, etc. that begin with a character. I tried just typing one character and searching, but this resulted in "your search term must have 2 or more characters." Is there anything in the SOSL that show me everything that starts with D for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't search with only one character in SOSL. The system enforces a two character minimum, not including wild card characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can not search with one character but you can create report and add filter for displaying all data.

Name **starts with** "X"